# Cypress - userAgent switch

Tags: jquery, environment-variables, cypress

I am unable to change/override userAgent using config file.
my cypress json:

```
env object: {
    "platform" : "mobile"
}
```

my plugins/index.js

```
module.exports = (on, options, config) => {
.
.
several on()s
.
.

on(config => {
    if (config.env.platform === 'desktop') {
      config.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.109 Safari/537.36'
    } else if (config.env.platform === 'mobile') {
      config.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1'
    }
    return config
  }) 
}
```

The error is: Error: You must pass a valid event name when registering a plugin.

I totally get it, I am unable to change it during runtime, but before that via config should work. config is passed into module.export, so I'm clueless. What did I miss?

note: Viewport is not an option, I need to use userAgent and cy.visit() header info modification is deprecated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle looks ok, you should be able to change user agent in plugins.

The syntax is wrong though, `on()` is catching an event and it needs an event name parameter: `on('<event>', config => {`.

But you don't really have or need an event for this, just modify the config inline

```
module.exports = (on, options, config) => {

  ...

  if (config.env.platform === 'desktop') {
    config.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.109 Safari/537.36'
  } 

  if (config.env.platform === 'mobile') {
    config.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1'
  }

  return config
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems config.env is not defined. config should be a reference of cypress.json, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you want in `cypress.json` add a property `"env": { "platform": "mobile" }` - but that's a bit permanent. Better to add in the script in `package.json` - `"cypress:mobile": "yarn cypress open --env platform=mobile"`. [ref](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4-env)

Comment: It's already in cypress.json and in the plugin.js give me env is not defined error in the condition. Btw. good point to add to package.json

Comment: Setting in cypress.json I get true for `console.log(config.env.platform === 'mobile')`. It should look like [Option #1](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-1-configuration-file).

Comment: Makes sense, my index.js does not have a reference to my cypress.json. Weird, but thanks for confirming my principle is ok.

Comment: `cypress.json` is passed in to `module.exports = (on, options, config) => {` as the config parameter. It looks like you're mistyping something.

Comment: Accepted your answer, everything is good. I had to add the first two conditions in the beginning of the export, then returning the config in the end of the module export after my ons. Works perfectly. Thanks Fody!!!

Comment: Do you have any idea why the userAgent under config is still null using the code above?

Comment: Sorry no idea, it does not occur for me.